# Tanuki upgrade: JVM configuration version

Tags: tanuki

I am currently using the old tanuki version 3.2.3, and moving to the newest one 3.5.25.
I followed the upgrading documentation: modify my script, change the jar and binary wrapper… etc. 
Debugging during the JVM launch, I could see that every  additional param defined in my wrapper.conf appears as follows:

```
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2014/07/03 13:41:08 | Command[0] : java
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2014/07/03 13:41:08 | Command[1] : -Djava.system.class.loader=myClass
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2014/07/03 13:41:08 | Command[2] : -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
```

But there are some extra params, and I don´t know where they are set up:

```
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2014/07/03 13:41:08 | Command[30] : -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2014/07/03 13:41:08 | Command[31] : -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2014/07/03 13:41:08 | Command[32] : -Dwrapper.service=TRUE
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2014/07/03 13:41:08 | Command[33] : -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10
```

Specially annoying is the version one. It is still the old one. Does anybody know where I could change this configuration params?

Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org

Thanks!
Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tanuki library was imported by a dependency. Doesn´t matter the properties in my project, they will be overwritten.
The solution: using maven discard these dependencies or overwrite them.